# A potential PHP memory hog or not?

Tags: php, design-patterns, memory-leaks, classloader

Hey, i'm in need of advice. Is this little function i wrote "good" or is it going to be a resource hog?
It's used in the following way:

```
$login = load_class('LoginClass');
```

or

```
load_class('LoginClassTwo', false); // for singletons and stuff
$loginTwo = LoginClassTwo::getInstance();
```

Here's the function

```
function load_class($class, $instantiate = TRUE){

static $obj = array(); // holds the instancec of the classes

$l = strtolower($class); // the name of the file is the name of the class but lowercased

if (isSet($obj[$l])) { // Do we have an instance?

    return $obj[$l]; 
}

$file = 'classess/' . $l . '.class.php';
if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) { // Can we read the file?

    include $file;

    if ($instantiate == FALSE) { // Do we need to instantiate?

        $obj[$l] = TRUE;
    } else {

        $obj[$l] = new $class;
    }

    return $obj[$l];
}

return FALSE;  }
```

I'm concerned that this method is ineffective and it's going to consume too much memory or am i wrong? And is there a better practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern, known as a registry, or service locator.

There *can* be an issue with a global registry of objects, in that these objects are not reclaimed until the script ends. If one of those objects uses a lot of memory, then there you go. However, in it self, this isn't a problem, memory wise.

You should consider which objects you want to hold on globally though. It's a generally accepted truthism that global objects contribute to the overall complexity and coupling of a program. Maybe you could pass some of them as parameters in the constructor, rather than addressing them globally? That entirely depends on the use case of course.

Lastly - php has a feature called [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), whereby it will load a class from file, if it's not already defined. You should hook in to this instead of putting the logic in your registry.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think i'll write a full registry class to hold my class instances. I'll post it here tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any memory hog kind of thing in your code.. If you experiance any such thing. it is probably the class you are loading

Comment: I'm asking if there is such possibility, not that the code itself will leak ;)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a native __autoload function for classes. it is run any time you attempt to create a new object from a class that does not yet exist. the function will try to include a class file using the name of the class as the class file. this is why many projects use one file per class. this way you never need to manually load a class again, and classes never get loaded unless needed. See the following link.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php